# What are the 1000 ports that nmap scans by default?

Tags: port, nmap

The [Nmap website](https://nmap.org/book/man-port-specification.html) states:

```
By default, Nmap scans the most common 1,000 ports for each protocol.
```

What are these 1000 ports? I need the exact port numbers.

Answer (score 2):

The port numbers are determined by the port frequency values in the `nmap-services` file. You can get Nmap to print a list of ports and port ranges scanned for a given invocation by using the "Grepable" output with the verbose flag:

```
nmap -v -oG - | grep "Ports scanned"
```

Comment: How do I find it on Windows?

Comment: @AnuShibinJosephRaj Instead of `grep` use `findstr`, or just look at the output of the `nmap` command. There are only 4 lines of output.

Answer (score 0):

`sort -r -k3 /usr/share/nmap/nmap-services | less`

`grep /tcp /usr/share/nmap/nmap-services | sort -r -k3 | less`

`grep /udp /usr/share/nmap/nmap-services | sort -r -k3 | less`

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.